# Storing results of query in cache

Tags: c#, list, caching, active-directory

I have a query that is going out to AD and grabbing all of the emails. My problem is, is that the query is taking quite a long time to execute (15-20 seconds via `AJAX`) to pull around 3,000 email addresses. I am considering storing the result set (which is in a list) in the `memory cache`. I am throwing the list into a drop-down to populate it with the emails. Here is my query:

```
    public class EmailDetails
    {
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string EmailDisplayName { get; set; }
    }

    public List<EmailDetails> EmailInformation { get; set; } 

    [WebMethod]
    public static List<EmailDetails> GetEmails()
    {
        List<EmailDetails> emailAddresses = new List<EmailDetails>();

        //queries AD to pull all users
        var search = new DirectorySearcher();
        search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(mail=*)(displayName=*))";
        search.PageSize = 1000;

        using (var results = search.FindAll())
        {
            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                emailAddresses.Add(new EmailDetails
                {
                    EmailAddress = result.Properties["mail"][0].ToString(),
                    EmailDisplayName = result.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString()
                });
            }
        }

        //sort email address list alphabetically and return sorted list
        List<EmailDetails> sortedEmailAddresses = emailAddresses.OrderBy(o => o.EmailDisplayName).ToList();
        return sortedEmailAddresses;
```

So my dilemma is, I am trying to find a way to speed up the process of the drop-down being loaded with the returned list. What would be the best way to achieve this? Memory cache? I am open to any options that you all deem reasonable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf.aspx store it in the Application. It gets cleaned every time you recycle the application pool, stays up the rest of the time. Nothing fancy, does the job.

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<EmailDetails> GetEmails()
{
    if(HttpContext.Current.Application["sortedEmailAddresses"]==null) {

        List<EmailDetails> emailAddresses = new List<EmailDetails>();

        //queries AD to pull all users
        var search = new DirectorySearcher();
        search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(mail=*)(displayName=*))";
        search.PageSize = 1000;

        using (var results = search.FindAll())
        {
            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                emailAddresses.Add(new EmailDetails
                {
                    EmailAddress = result.Properties["mail"][0].ToString(),
                    EmailDisplayName = result.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString()
                });
            }
        }

        //sort email address list alphabetically and return sorted list
        List<EmailDetails> sortedEmailAddresses = emailAddresses.OrderBy(o => o.EmailDisplayName).ToList();
        HttpContext.Current.Application["sortedEmailAddresses"] = sortedEmailAddresses;
    }
    return HttpContext.Current.Application["sortedEmailAddresses"] as List<EmailDetails>;
}
```

Comment: How would I implement that? (i.e. where would I place the stated syntax?)